# Image percentage not restricting

Tags: html, css

I have a div that I am giving a width of 60% to.

**CSS**

```css
#image {
    float:left;
    width:60%;
    background-image:url('cleaning.jpg');
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<div id="image">
     <img src="cleaning.jpg" />
</div>
```

My issue is that the image is being displayed at full size across the entire page!

How do I restrict it to the div it is being enclosed in?

Thanks!

Comment: Why have you got it as a background image as as well as an image in the HTML?

Comment: ^same questions, and also, JSFiddle this please!

Comment: It was a mistake, I have removed the css background image. Question has been solved below :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure why you have a background image and a normal image. Background images will never scale with the container. I think your problem however is you need to set your image width as well. try

**CSS**

```css
#image {
    float:left;
    width:60%;
    background-image:url('cleaning.jpg');
}
#image img {
    width:100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<div id="image">
     <img src="cleaning.jpg" />
</div>
```

Example with http://jsfiddle.net/f5Ls3/

Example without http://jsfiddle.net/f5Ls3/1/

Comment: I forgot to add the img width 100%! Cheers..I tried both methods for the image to display but forgot to remove it from the css before posting!

Comment: #image img{width:100%;}

Answer (score 1):

The likelihood is that you need to manage the overflow of the element.
Try the following:

```css
#image {
    float:left;
    width:60%;
    background-image:url('cleaning.jpg') no-repeat;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are having is that you set the parent div to have a width of 60%. You did not give the specific image element for that div a specific width. I hope this helped, I'm not 100% sure that I am correct but that is what this site is for, a question and answer format to help you work your bugs out. The issue how I see it is that you are setting the width of the specific div, and adding a background image to it which would not require you to set a `<img></img>` element. So in reality you have two copies of the image in the same spot, one which is 60% width, the second full size image covers the other. You must set the `<img></img>` element's width.

**CSS:**

```css
#image {
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
    /* No need for a background image to be set if you're using <img></img> */
}

#image img {
   width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, you appear to be using two competing techniques - you've got a background-image on the container div, but you've also got the same image contained by the container div. Pick One.

For the background-image technique, you probably want to use something like:

```css
#image {
    width: 60%;
    background:url('cleaning.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```